# Lambda expression in haskell has different type

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

I am trying to learn Haskell.

We have very simple functions. As I understood all the following are equivalent.

But I don't understand why `f2` and `f2'` have different types, and why exactly `Integer`.

Also, if I specify the type of `f2'` manually, it accepts it and works same as `f2`.

```
f x = x + 1
-- f :: Num a => a -> a

f' = \x -> x + 1
-- f' :: Num a => a -> a

f2 a b = a + b
-- f2 :: Num a => a -> a -> a

f2' = \a b -> a + b
-- f2 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer

f2'' = \a -> \b -> a + b
-- f2 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The answer to this good question is not all that interesting: that happens merely due to a technicality called the *monomorphism restriction*. For a detailed explanation of the reason why the behaviour is different, go to the "When does it happen?" section of the answer to the linked question. You can tell GHC to use the more general type in all cases by adding the corresponding type signature -- e.g. `f2' :: Num a => a -> a`

Comment: I understand this is a duplicate question, but you know how it is when you don't know something good enough in order to make a good question.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. (By the way, don't worry about having posted a duplicate question. Non-obvious duplicates are useful as a signpost for people who land in them; furthermore, the answer here is arcane enough that it would be unreasonable to expect you to have guessed what to look for.)